# std::numeric_limits::digits10<float> and precision after the dot

Tags: c++, floating-point

When `std::numeric_limits::digits10<float>`  return 7 does it mean that I have 7 significatif figures after the dot or that 7 with the left part?

For instance is it like:

```
1.123456
12.12345
```

or is it like

```
12.1234657
```

Comment: Did you tried it?

Comment: Ceros: no how can I do ?

Comment: Ceros: by try to make a round trip ?

Comment: By making a test application. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10

Comment: ceros: ok so with your link i understand that is it like my first couple of examples, and the second is wrong

Comment: floating-point means the significand stays whereas the point floats, regardless of the base. The precision in digits here is the precision of the significand, so it's not the number of digits after decimal point. Imagine how float stores numbers like 1000000000000.1234567?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10)

> The value of std::numeric_limits::digits10 is the number of base-10 digits that can be represented by the type T without change, that is, any number with this many decimal digits can be converted to a value of type T and back to decimal form, without change due to rounding or overflow. For base-radix types, it is the value of digits (digits-1 for floating-point types) multiplied by log
>   10(radix) and rounded down.

And later

> The standard 32-bit IEEE 754 floating-point type has a 24 bit fractional part (23 bits written, one implied), which may suggest that it can represent 7 digit decimals (24 * std::log10(2) is 7.22), but relative rounding errors are non-uniform and some floating-point values with 7 decimal digits do not survive conversion to 32-bit float and back: the smallest positive example is 8.589973e9, which becomes 8.589974e9 after the roundtrip. These rounding errors cannot exceed one bit in the representation, and digits10 is calculated as (24-1)*std::log10(2), which is 6.92. Rounding down results in the value 6.

That means, e.g.

```
cout << std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10; // 6
cout << std::numeric_limits<float>::digits; // 24
```

the second one is the number of digits in the mantissa while the first one the number of decimal digits that can safely be represented across aforementioned conversions.

TL;DR: it's your first case.